# Estimate transition density function of Ito Diffusion SDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, estimation

Suppose I have an [Ito diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_diffusion) SDE:
$$
dX_t = b(X_t) \,dt + \sigma(X_t)\,dB_t
$$
in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I only know the values of $b$ and $\sigma$ at specific (incidentally random) points $R=\{r_i\;|\;i=1\text{ to }n\}$, but I can interpolate the values to simulate the SDE if needed.

Then,  $$
\mathcal{A} = \sum_i b^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
+
\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\sum_j [\sigma \sigma^T]_{ij} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}
$$ is the [infinitesimal generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_generator_(stochastic_processes)) of the process.

I want to estimate the transition density function of $X_t$.
That is, estimate the heat kernel solution of $u_t = \mathcal{A} u$. (Please point out any inaccuracies in the above!)

To simplify, I'll try to estimate $p(t,x|s,x)$ only. Specifically, I want the values at $R$; i.e. for each $i$, I'd like $p_i(t) := p(t,r_i|0,r_i)$.

---

My first thought is to use the Fokker-Planck equation:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p = \mathcal{A}^*p,
$$
where $\mathcal{A^*}$ is the adjoint infinitesimal generator given by:
$$
\mathcal{A^*}f(t,y) = 
-\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ b(y)f(t,y) \right]
+ \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \left[ \sigma^2(y) f(t,y) \right].
$$
So I can numerically integrate this starting from $p_0(0,x)=1_{x=r_i}$, for each $i$.

Questions:

1. Does this make sense?
2. Is there a better way to do this by simulating $X_t$ and doing statistics on it (that would be more robust or faster)?

Comment: @AIM_BLB I did end up simulating the SDE and Monte Carlo estimating the probabilities with kernel density estimation. This was quite slow, and I think an importance sampling approach would do better. (I think in most cases, solving the PDE would be way faster though, depending on $n$).

Comment: @AIM_BLB Haha, sorry. If you find something good, please post it back here as an answer! I'm still interested. Maybe check out Milstein et al, *Transition density estimation for stochastic differential equations via forward-reverse representations* btw.

Comment: If you know the coefficients $b$ and $\sigma$ and you are in dimension $d=1$, then solving the Fokker-Planck equation is probably the way to go. You could also solve $p_t+Ap=0$ and $p(T,x)=\mathbb{1}_A(x)$ to obtain $\mathbb{E}( \mathbb{1}_A(X_T)|X_t=x)=\mathbb{P}(X_T\in A|X_t=x)$. Set $A=(-\infty, y]$ to get the CDF, then numerically differentiate to get the PDF (and of course you could just simulate a bunch of SDEs and average then differentiate, by passing the FK PDE). This is probably not much better than your SDE>MC>Kernel method though in terms of speed.